# Python insertion sort for two lists

Tags: python, sorting, time-complexity

I'm trying to make a function which merges 2 lists and returns the total sorted list.

```
def insertionSort(alist,blist):

total = alist + blist

for index in range(1,len(total)):
    currentvalue = total[index]
    position = index

    while position>0 and total[position-1]>currentvalue:
        total[position]=total[position-1]
        position = position-1

        total[position]=currentvalue
        print(total)
```

It works but It gives me as output something like this:

```
>>> insertionSort([9,8,7], [5,4,3])

[8, 9, 7, 5, 4, 3]
[8, 7, 9, 5, 4, 3]
[7, 8, 9, 5, 4, 3]
[7, 8, 5, 9, 4, 3]
[7, 5, 8, 9, 4, 3]
[5, 7, 8, 9, 4, 3]
[5, 7, 8, 4, 9, 3]
[5, 7, 4, 8, 9, 3]
[5, 4, 7, 8, 9, 3]
[4, 5, 7, 8, 9, 3]
[4, 5, 7, 8, 3, 9]
[4, 5, 7, 3, 8, 9]
[4, 5, 3, 7, 8, 9]
[4, 3, 5, 7, 8, 9]
[3, 4, 5, 7, 8, 9]
```

But I want only the last line(result). What can I do?

Also, I'm curious about the complexity of this function if both of lists are not sorted. Is this `o((alist+blist)^2)`?

Warning : I know how to use `list.sort()`. This question is about [this](http://interactivepython.org/runestone/static/pythonds/SortSearch/TheInsertionSort.html) algo but for 2 lists.

Comment: you know of the BIF ``sorted()``, right?

Comment: @LarsVegas sure ;)

Comment: maybe you should re-phrase the question

Comment: @LarsVegas You're right, but I don't know how can I clarify what exactly I'd like to get. I'm not a native speaker

Comment: @LarsVegas I'd like to use the same algorithme but get another output, also, I'd like to know the complexity of this code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may merge both the lists say,

```
   l1 = [10,5,33] and 
   l2 = [36, 12,9]

   newl = l1.extend(l2)

   Output: [10, 5, 33, 36, 12, 9]
```

And then do:

```
    newl.sort()

    Output: [5, 9, 10, 12, 33, 36]
```

Answer (score 0):

The most obvious way would be

```
def insertionSort(alist,blist):

    return sorted(alist + blist)
```

The sorting itself in your code works, you just forgot to add a return statement

```
def insertionSort(alist,blist):

    total = alist + blist

    for index in range(1,len(total)):
        currentvalue = total[index]
        position = index

        while position>0 and total[position-1]>currentvalue:
            total[position]=total[position-1]
            position = position-1

            total[position]=currentvalue
    print(total)
    return total
```

Demo:

```
a = [3, 2, 88, 99]
b = [9, 5]
def insertionSort(alist, blist):

    total = alist + blist

    for index in range(1,len(total)):
        currentvalue = total[index]
        position = index

        while position>0 and total[position-1]>currentvalue:
            total[position]=total[position-1]
            position = position-1

            total[position]=currentvalue
    print(total)
    return total

In [18]: insertionSort(a,b)
[2, 3, 5, 9, 88, 99]
Out[18]: [2, 3, 5, 9, 88, 99]
```

Comment: thank you for the answer! But I'm trying to make something like this http://www.cs.usfca.edu/~galles/visualization/ComparisonSort.html

Comment: I think it's just impossible to get only the last line using this algorithme, thanks anyway!

Comment: @Martin You're misunderstanding some concepts – printing is different from returning.